# PHP CLI System_Daemon and error_reporting options ignored?

Tags: php, daemon, error-reporting

I'm making a daemon with System_Daemon for PHP. 
I can't get the default php error_reporting off.

I've tried

```
<?php
   error_reporting(0);
   set_ini('display_errors','off');
?>
```

but the warnings/notices are still showing when I execute the script from the console.
Any ideas why this is happening or what I'm missing ? Probably it's some setting in System_Daemon ? :)

Comment: Where did you put these lines?

Comment: These are the starting lines of the script. Now things work. Thanks for trying to help! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is ini_set not set_ini

```
ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

Look at here http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php you have to set o to hide notice/warnings.

Comment: ohh... yeah. .. that was the problem..thanks ! it's strange it didn't show any fatal errors about the missing function but it showed tons of other errors ... :)

Comment: Yes I've read them but everything was only notices about not set variables. Anyway it works fine now :)